# How benefitial would it be to have specific breed tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was looking for schnauzer related questions but it became a bit hard as there's is no actual tag for it other than [dogs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dogs), and it got me wondering if it would be of benefit to start having tags for specific breeds, not only for [dogs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dogs) but also [cats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cats),[fish](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fish),[rabbits](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rabbits), and so on. I think it would make looking for specific questions much more easier, but that's just my opinion.

What is your opinion on this?

PS: This is not a formal feature-request, I'm digging up on the idea to see if I should or shouldn't go through with it.